# Setting text for NSTextView with an NSString variable, considering reference counting

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsstring, nstextview

I have the following code in a function in my .m file:

> desc = [my executeFunction]; // desc is returned by executeFunction
>   data = [desc objectAtIndex:0]; // data is declared in the .h file
>   data2 = [desc objectAtIndex:1];
>   [myTextField setString:data]; // myTextField is connected to an NSTextView in IB
>   [myTextField setString:data2];

How am I supposed to be writing the 4th and 5th lines? How / where do I release data and data2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You haven't received `data` or `data2` from a method with a selector containing `alloc`, `new` or `copy` or a function with a name containing `Create`, so you are not responsible for releasing them.

Have a look at http://boredzo.org/cocoa-and-cocoa-touch-intro/.

Answer (score 1):

Revise the [Cocoa Memory Management Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) and determine whether releasing is necessary in this case. There are very specific, yet very simple rules regarding a `retain` and `release` pattern. Commit these rules to memory (pun intended).